# Hibernate Search: Exception when trying to sort by long field with @SortableField

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I updated Hibernate Search to 5.5 and I saw that I should use the annotation @SortableField on all fields that I want to be sortable.
It works fine for String fields and also for a Double field.
But when I try to sort a Long field, I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'organizationStatistics.viewsSort' (expected=NUMERIC). Use UninvertingReader or index with docvalues.
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.checkField(DocValues.java:208) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.getNumeric(DocValues.java:227) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$NumericComparator.getNumericDocValues(FieldComparator.java:167) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator$NumericComparator.doSetNextReader(FieldComparator.java:153) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.search.SimpleFieldComparator.getLeafComparator(SimpleFieldComparator.java:36) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldValueHitQueue.getComparators(FieldValueHitQueue.java:183) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldCollector$NonScoringCollector.getLeafCollector(TopFieldCollector.java:141) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:763) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:486) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:474) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.LazyQueryState.search(LazyQueryState.java:100) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.2.Final.jar:5.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.updateTopDocs(QueryHits.java:250) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.2.Final.jar:5.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.<init>(QueryHits.java:145) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.2.Final.jar:5.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.HSQueryImpl.getQueryHits(HSQueryImpl.java:480) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.2.Final.jar:5.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.HSQueryImpl.queryEntityInfos(HSQueryImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.2.Final.jar:5.5.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:199) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.5.2.Final.jar:5.5.2.Final]
at com.third.rest.resources.retailers.PromotionTemplateService.hibernateSearch(PromotionTemplateService.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
at com.third.rest.resources.retailers.PromotionTemplateService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4a03a5f2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at com.third.rest.resources.retailers.PromotionTemplateService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9b560b8.hibernateSearch(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.third.rest.resources.retailers.PromotionTemplateResourceImpl.list(PromotionTemplateResourceImpl.java:123) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor586.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy258.list(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor586.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) ~[jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185) ~[jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) ~[jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) ~[jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) ~[jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) ~[jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) ~[jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-server-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715) [jersey-servlet-1.18.jar:1.18]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at com.third.rest.util.LogRawRequestFilter.doFilter(LogRawRequestFilter.java:61) [classes/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:140) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:301) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

This is how my field is declared:

```
@Column(name = "views")
@Field(name = "viewsSort", analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES)
@SortableField(forField = "viewsSort")
private Long view;
```

I couldn't find a straight answer for this and everything looks to be declared correctly. Hope you guys can help.

Comment: could you try version 5.5.3.Final ? Several fixes were made around the new @SortableField annotation. If that doesn't help, please report on JIRA: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH/summary

Comment: @Sanne, thanks for answering, I'll live the link here of our talk in Jira.
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2283